# How to implement 'wrapper feature/function' manually?

Tags: c

Lets see what is wrapper function first with example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function    (also worth looking)

(https://goo.gl/nGiMkl)

**--wrap symbol**

Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to `__wrap_symbol`. Any undefined reference to `__real_symbol` will be resolved to symbol. This can be used to provide a wrapper for a system function. The wrapper function should be called `__wrap_symbol`. If it wishes to call the system function, it should call `__real_symbol`. Here is a trivial example:

```
void *
__wrap_malloc (int c)
{
  printf ("malloc called with %ld\n", c);
  return __real_malloc (c);
}
```

If you link other code with this file using --wrap malloc, then all calls to malloc will call the function `__wrap_malloc` instead. The call to `__real_malloc` in `__wrap_malloc` will call the real malloc function. You may wish to provide a `__real_malloc` function as well, so that links without the --wrap option will succeed. If you do this, you should not put the definition of `__real_malloc` in the same file as `__wrap_malloc`; if you do, the assembler may resolve the call before the linker has a chance to wrap it to malloc.

**Problem statement**:

1. Wrapper is a feature provided by **Compiler**
2. In my project I need to implement similar kind of program which needed **wrapper function**. But the compiler my project is using **(Wind River Diab Compiler)** not support *wrapper function*.
3. So the real question is can I implement similar functionality with a compiler which not support **wrapper function/feature**. Means can I implement **wrapper function** manually.

Complete is project is on **C**  language only

**PS:** Question is not about `malloc()`. its just an example.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=LD_PRELOAD+hook  (Assuming that your OS supports `LD_PRELOAD`)

Comment: @BenVoigt doesn't really limit itself to replacing unresolved symbols at link time though, right? For the `__real_` replacement I mean

Comment: @PeterT: `RTLD_NEXT` flag to `dlsym` helps with that.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you please explain a little. I am not able to get what you mentioned.